# How to add button on child row in lightning tree grid

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I ma newbie to lightning component and I am using the lightning tree grid view in that I like to add some button on one column in child rows. I searched for that option but I couldn't find it.

Please help me out how we can achieve this.

[image]

**Lightning Component**

```
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <lightning:treeGrid aura:id="accTree" 
                            columns="{!v.gridColumns}" 
                            data="{!v.gridData}" 
                            keyField="name" 
                            expandedRows="{!v.gridExpandedRows}"/>
    </div>
```

**Lightning Controller**

```
var columns = [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'Order',
                label: 'Order'
            },
            {
                type: 'currency',
                fieldName: 'Total',
                label: 'Total'
            },

           **{
                type: 'Button',
                fieldName: 'EstimatedDeliveryDate',
                label: 'Estimated Delivery Date'
            },**
]
```

I tried adding the button as type "button: but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Only first column can't be made as button . Otherwise we have an type called button and we can pass the typeattributes to align the button other than the first column

```
             type: 'button',
               fieldName: 'Sample',
                label: 'Test',
                    typeAttributes: {
                        iconName: '',
                        name: 'sample', 
                        title: 'testtet',
                        label:'testtet',
                        alternativeText:'Example',
                        variant: 'brand',                      
                        disabled: false
                    }
```